# Shopify password update using Shopify API

Tags: php, shopify, change-password

Can we update password for a User or Customer that already exists in Shopify using the Shopify API?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. Should they not do it themselves?

Comment: Hey @Appleman I don't know they do it or not,but I want to do it myself. And want to know the possibilities. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Mmm, I have gone through the API and don't see anything that can help. But I'll keep thinking and let you know as soon as I have a solution.

Comment: thanks keep thinking,as you get solution please let me know :)

Comment: Yes, it possible using the customer ( https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/customer ) API. You will need to use third party API and private apps for the same. Using user email, you will need to find user ID using `customers/search.json?query=email:'.$customer_email.'` . After getting the id of customer you can update password by passing PUT request with customer id, password and confirm the password. I had implemented it for one of my client. I am 100% sure its possible,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The User endpoint is available for Shopify Plus stores, but it is currently read only - no user management is possible via this API

https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/user

Answer (score 9):

Although the API documentation does not say anything about changing the customer password, you can do actually change the customer password using the PUT /admin/customers/#{id}.json endpoint. Note that my answer is only for customers and not for users.

I have tested it, successfully changed the customer password and log in on the store with the new password. During my tests I used a private app and a normal app both with successful results.

Example:

PUT /admin/customers/5206361102.json

Body:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "id": 5206361102,
    "password": "mypass2",
    "password_confirmation": "mypass2"
  }
}
```

If you need the customer id you can use the the GET /admin/customers/search.json end point to find it.

For example you can get the id from the results of this:

GET /admin/customers/search.json?query=email:customeremail@customerdomain.com

Result:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "id": 5206556238,
    ... other parameters ...
  }
}
```

Thank you to [@spviradiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3300870/spviradiya) for the comment that pointed me out to this answer, I have tested it and implemented it into my project.

Comment: Great answer! I'd only add `"send_email_welcome": false` as pointed out by Abhijit, just to avoid spamming them with an unnecessary email.

Comment: I'm using `/admin/api/2021-10/customers/<ID>.json`, but yes, this still works. I'm using Shopify Plus and the admin API.

Answer (score 3):

```
        PUT /admin/customers/#{id}.json
    {
      "customer": {
        "id": 207119551,
        "password": "newpass",
        "password_confirmation": "newpass",
        "send_email_welcome": false
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

NO, its not possible for now in the normal shopify store API. May this type of feature they expanding in to the next plus version but to be honest Plus is costly so very rare people using it compare to normal shopify store.

Comment: I'm always shocked to find anyone who can afford to use Plus at all. They must be making millions in annual sales!

Answer (score 0):

If You want to update password of your store's customer using shopify Api then yes it is possible. Here is Sample Code:-

```
$password = array(
          "customer"=>array(
              'id'=>$customerid,
              'password'=> $new_password,
              'password_confirmation'=>$confirm_password    

          )
      );
$customer = $shopify("PUT /admin/customers/$customerid.json" , $password);
```

You can update shopify store's customer password this way.
But if you are talking about user then this API us only available for shopify plus store.check this link:- https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/plus/user

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NO,

Still in 2019 it is not possible it is just read only. Even you can visit this [link](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/plus/user)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the password of your user using the shopify API please try to use the below code:-

```html
$updatePassword = array(
          "customer"=>array(
              'id'=>$userId,
              'password'=> $updatedPassword,
              'password_confirmation'=>$confirm_updatedPassword,
              'send_reset_password_email': true    

          )
      );
$updateCustomer = $shopify("PUT /admin/customers/$userId.json" , $updatePassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Shopify API to change the password for a user or client who is already registered with Shopify. You can use the customerReset mutation to accomplish this. The revised password and the client's email address are required for this modification. An email with a link to reset their username and password is sent to the customer in response to a successful mutation.

```
mutation customerReset($email: String!, $password: String!) {
customerReset(email: $email, password: $password) {
customer {
  id
  email
    }
   }
 }
```

Please be aware that only Shopify customers who's accounts were initially set up can have their passwords updated. The customerReset mutation cannot be used to create a fresh client.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Shopify provides an API that allows you to update a customer's password programmatically. The Shopify API has an endpoint specifically designed for managing customers, including updating their passwords.

To update a customer's password using the Shopify API, you need to perform the following steps:

1. **Authenticate Your API Requests:** Ensure that you have the necessary authentication credentials (API key, API secret key, and access token) to authenticate your API requests with Shopify.
2. **Make a PUT Request to Update the Customer's Password:** Use the Customers API endpoint along with the customer's ID or email to update their password. Here's an example using cURL:

```bash
curl -X PUT "https://your-store-name.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/customers/customer_id.json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Basic BASE64ENCODED(API_KEY:API_PASSWORD)" \
-d '{
  "customer": {
    "id": customer_id,
    "password": "new_password",
    "password_confirmation": "new_password"
  }
}'
```

Replace `your-store-name` with your actual Shopify store name, `customer_id` with the ID of the customer whose password you want to update, and `new_password` with the desired new password.

Please note that the API version (e.g., `2023-10`) should be updated to the specific version you're using or the latest stable version available at the time of your API request.

3. **Handle API Response:** Handle the API response to ensure that the password update request was successful. The response will indicate whether the password was updated or if there were any errors.
4. **Securely Manage Passwords:** Always follow best practices for managing passwords, including securely storing and transmitting them. Encourage customers to use strong, unique passwords to protect their accounts.

It's crucial to handle customers' password changes securely and in compliance with data protection regulations. Additionally, using HTTPS and secure methods for transmitting sensitive data is recommended when interacting with APIs.

Remember to test API requests in a safe environment before implementing them in a production setting, especially when dealing with sensitive customer information like passwords.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).